# How do I write a JPA criteria query that matches a collection exactly?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteriaquery

I’m using JPA 2.0 with Hibernate 4.1.0.Final.  I have a couple of classes, Groups and GroupMembers.  Each GroupMember is tied to a user object

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
public class Group    
{
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-strategy")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;
    …


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
    private Set<GroupMember> members;



@Entity
@Table(name = "sb_msg_group_member")
public class GroupMember
{
    …

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private User user;
```

Is it possible to write a JPA criteria query that given a java.util.Set of User objects, would return the groups whose members match exactly that Set?  I tried the below …

```
    final CriteriaBuilder builder = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Group> criteria = builder.createQuery(Group.class);
    final Root<Group> groupRoot = criteria.from(Group.class);
    final Set<GroupMember> groupMembers = new HashSet<GroupMember>();
    for (final User user : users)
    {
        final GroupMember groupMember = new GroupMember();
        groupMember.setUser(user);
        groupMembers.add(groupMember);
    }   // for
    criteria.where(builder.equal(groupRoot.get(Group_.members), groupMembers));
    final TypedQuery<Group> results = m_entityManager.createQuery(criteria);
```

but it fails with the exception …

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2611)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2586)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2510)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2259)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2040)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1837)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1275)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler$3.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:258)
    at org.mainco.subco.messaging.repo.MessageDaoImpl.findGroupByMembers(MessageDaoImpl.java:144)
    at org.mainco.subco.messaging.repo.MessageDaoIT.testFindGroupByMembers(MessageDaoIT.java:83)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need different roots for each and every user, as each of them is different from the others (untested):

```
final CriteriaBuilder builder = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Group> criteria = builder.createQuery(Group.class);
final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
final Root<Group> group = criteria.from(Group.class);
for (final User user : users)
{
    final Root<GroupMember> memberRoot = group.join(Group_.members);
    final Predicate p = builder.equal(memberRoot.get(GroupMember_.user), user);
    predicates.add(p);
}   // for
predicates.add(builder.equals(builder.count(group.get(Group_.members)),users.size()))
criteria.where(builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));
final TypedQuery<Group> results = m_entityManager.createQuery(criteria);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in a "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: No value specified for parameter 2" exception.  The query produced was "select group0_.ID as ID68_, group0_.CLASSROOM_ID as CLASSROOM3_68_, group0_.NAME as NAME68_, group0_.CREATOR as CREATOR68_ from sb_msg_group group0_ cross join sb_msg_group_member members1_ where group0_.ID=members1_.GROUP_ID and .=? limit ?"

Comment: Well, parameter 2 is the `limit ?` bit, have you tried adding a `query.setMaxResults(...)` to the query?

More to the point, what is a GroupMember (I assume it's a JPA entity), and why does the `and .=? ` bit get produced?

Comment: I don't know what the ".=?" is, I cut and pasted your code and that is what it produced.  Yes, the GroupMember is a JPA entity, I defined it in the question but if I need to add more information, let me know and I can take care of that.

Comment: To correct compilation errors, I changed "final Root<GroupMember> group = criteria.from(Group.class);" to "final Root<Group> group = criteria.from(Group.class);" and "final Predicate p = builder.equal(groupRoot.get(GroupMember_.user), user);" to "final Predicate p = builder.equal(memberRoot.get(GroupMember_.user), user);" but got the exception, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')) and groupmembe2_.USER_ID='userid' and (groupmembe2_.ID in (.))' at line 1".

Comment: Can you post here the full SQL produced?

Comment: Sure teh SQL is "select group0_.ID as ID70_, group0_.CLASSROOM_ID as CLASSROOM3_70_, group0_.NAME as NAME70_, group0_.CREATOR as CREATOR70_ from sb_msg_group group0_ cross join sb_msg_group_member groupmembe1_ cross join sb_msg_group_member groupmembe2_ cross join sb_msg_group_member members3_ cross join sb_msg_group_member members4_ where group0_.ID=members3_.GROUP_ID and group0_.ID=members4_.GROUP_ID and groupmembe1_.USER_ID=? and (groupmembe1_.ID in (.)) and groupmembe2_.USER_ID=? and (groupmembe2_.ID in (.))"

Comment: Ok, we're getting close; Replace `final Root<GroupMember> memberRoot = criteria.from(GroupMember.class);` with `? = group.join(GroupMember.class);` and remove the last `predicates.add()` line; that should construct the proper SQL

Comment: Could you update your code?  I tried your suggestions but it produced a query where none of the users were passed as parameters. (SQL was too long pass in comments)

Comment: I've applied them to the question, have a look now. A similar thing happens in my own code and it works just fine.

Comment: Thx so its close but it fails in the following situation:  The group, G, contains users A and B, but you do a search with a Set containing only user A.  The code you have will return group G, even though it should not (G's members are not exactly "user A" only).

Comment: For that, you just need to check that the size of the group is equal to the size of the group you seek (barring degenerate cases where the same user is in that group twice). I've added the line `predicates.add(builder.equals(builder.count(group.get(Group_.members)),users.size()))` (untested) that expresses that.

Comment: The predicate produces the SQL " and count(.)=2" (in my example I was searching with "2" users in the Set.  Trying to figure out why the "." is getting put in there, but if you have any insights, wanted to let you know.  I appreciate your help with all this.

Comment: Ah, that's weird - I might be misunderstanding the Root<?> class; I'll take a shot at it again later when I'm at home; the idea was to check that the group had exactly these members (by counting them all).

Comment: It's ok ... changing the "count" to "size" allows it to work.  Thanks again for hte help.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a procedure in SQL and calling the same using JPA? I created the following for calling login procedure I created.

```
    @Query(nativeQuery = true,value = "{call Login_User(:username,:pass)}")  // call stored procedure 
    int loginUser(@Param("username")String username,@Param("pass")String pass);
```

And the SQL Procedure I had created was as following:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Login_User(IN username CHAR(12), IN pass text(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE password text(18);
    SELECT User_Password INTO password  FROM user WHERE User_ID = username;
    select if(STRCMP(pass,password)= 0,1,0) as str_compare;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!
I'm open to know more about the same. I know mine is more like a workaround rather than the solution :)