# Query a Entity by list of nested Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity `Book` which contain List of `Author` entity.

`Book` **ManyToMany** `Author`

**Book Entity**

```
public class Book{
   ...

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(name="BookAuthor",
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="bookId")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="authorId")})
   private List<Author> authors;

   ...
}
```

**Note:** There is no backward reference from Author to Book in Author entity.

I am trying to get all the books that have the exact list of authors.

This is what I have come up with so far:-

```
public List<Book> getBooksFromAuthors(List<Author> authors) {

   TypedQuery<Book> bookTypedQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Book b where b.authors = :authors", Book.class)
    .setParameter("authors", authors);
   return bookTypedQuery.getResultList(); // Error at this line
}
```

This gives an error:-

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet

How should I modify my query to get the desired result?

Comment: just a doubt, have you enabled hibernate logs? if so what query is it printing?

Comment: My original query is much bigger than this, the above is a toned down version of it. But what I can say is that the query makes a join with BookAuthor table.

Comment: clearly, just based on reading the JPA spec (free on the internet for all to see), you cannot do "List = List". You can use the IN operator

Comment: @BillyFrost: So you mean I should do something like `b.authors.id in :authorIds`. Please not that I am matching the exact authors with the books and IN would probably return books that consists any(I want all) of the authors in the `authorList`.

Comment: Take a look here, it may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090712/how-do-i-write-a-jpa-criteria-query-that-matches-a-collection-exactly

Comment: can you try passing list of author ids and do a 'IN' query. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126366/doing-an-in-query-with-hibernate

Comment: @Sandeep : Will using 'IN' give books with exactly matching list of authorIds?

Comment: @ParagKadam it works for exact as well as partial match also.

Comment: I want it to work exclusively for an exact match.

Comment: I mean you should look at basic JPQL docs before just guessing. IN syntax is well documented ... "value IN collection".