# jpa criteria query, match any of list passed as parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

I'm trying to write a DAO method where I select any number of Widgets that have a matching tag. So in entities like:

```
@Entity
public class Widget {
    @Id
    private id;

    @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Tag> tagList;
}


@Entity
public class Tag {
    @Id
    private int id;

    String tagValue;
}
```

and in my DAO, I'm trying to write a method that will take in a list of strings

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("tom");
myList.add("dick");
myList.add("harry");
```

to the DAO

```
public List<Widget> getWidgetsMatchingTags(EntityManager entityManager, List<String> tagValues) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Widget> query = cb.createQuery(Widget.class);
    Root<Widget> widgetRoot = query.from(Widget.class);
    Join<Widget, Tag> tagJoin = widgetRoot.join(Widget_.tagList);

    // this works
    query.select(widgetRoot).where(cb.and(
           cb.equal(tagJoin.get(Tag_.value), "tom")));

   // but if I try to add another predicate, it does not work, 
   // it returns a list size of 0

   query.select(widgetRoot).where(cb.and(
           cb.equal(tagJoin.get(Tag_.value), "tom")),
           cb.equal(tagJoin.get(Tag_.value), "harry"));

}
```

would like to be able to be able to match all or any of the given tags, and thought that that would be a matter of cb.and() or cb.or()

I google around and found a few link, like this on [collections](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/collection#NOT_MEMBER_OF), also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090712/how-do-i-write-a-jpa-criteria-query-that-matches-a-collection-exactly) which I don't think was totally relevant...I also went thru the pdf jpa documentation, the [online user guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria) and did not see this covered explicitly. Please let me know if I missed something

Also note that I need to match a *tag value*, as the string is a field of the tag obj.

thanks for any help!!

thanks for any help

Comment: *to match all or any of the given tags*: what do you mean? Is it all, or is it any?

Comment: wanted to be able to do either, as in pass in an arg such as a boolean, and depending on value call `cb.any()` or `cb.all()`

Comment: It's not just a matter of turning an `or` into an `and`. If you want to match any tag, then you just need `or` (or use `tagJoin.get(Tag_.value).in(acceptedTagValues)`). What you're doing with `and`, OTOH, can't work, because it only accepts a row if its tag value is equal to "tom" and "harry" at the same time, which is impossible. You'll need a subquery counting the number of tag values of a widget in the accepted set of values, and testing that this count is equal to the size of the set.

Comment: It looks like a ManyToMany relationship, shouldn't you have an additional table where to store the id pairs?

Comment: I ended up resolving it by creating a subquery, looping over the list of tags I wanted to find in the database, and creating a Predicate instnace of the subquery for the given search text. I then added the predicate array to the query.where() and that resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a Widget property on the Tag, like this:

```java
@ManyToOne
private Widget widget;
```

In case you want to match any tag, you even don't need a dynamic query. With [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA) it can be realized like this:

```java
List<Object> tags; // passed as a parameter

FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((Widget w,
                                   Tag tag) -> {
    SELECT(DISTINCT(w));
    FROM(w).JOIN(tag).ON(tag.getWidget() == w);
    WHERE(tags.contains(tag.getTagValue()));
});

query.createQuery(getEntityManager(), Widget.class).getResultList();
```

in case you want to match all the tags, you need a dynamic query:

```java
public List<Widget> filterWidgets(List<String> tags) {
    Function1<Tag, Boolean> dynamicFilter = buildAnd(tags);

    FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((Widget w,
                                       Tag tag) -> {

        SELECT(DISTINCT(w));
        FROM(w).JOIN(tag).ON(tag.getWidget() == w);
        WHERE(dynamicFilter.apply(tag));
    });
    return query.createQuery(getEntityManager(), Widget.class).getResultList();
}

private Function1<Tag, Boolean> buildAnd(List<String> tags) {
    Function1<Tag, Boolean> criteria = Function1.TRUE();

    for (String tag : tags)
        criteria = criteria.and(t -> t.getTagValue() == parameter(tag));

    return criteria;
}
```

with 3 tags this is the resulting query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t0.*  
FROM Widget t0  INNER JOIN Tag t1  ON (t1.widget_id = t0.id) 
WHERE (((t1.tag_value = ?1) AND (t1.tag_value = ?2)) AND (t1.tag_value = ?3))
```