# Hibernate : How to dynamically add attributes in where clause of hibernate native sql query language

Tags: hibernate

I need below query to be handled by hibernate.

```
select * from 
  (select ROWNUM rnum,
    fullData.* from 
    (select count(*) over () as rowcnt,
    origQry.*
    from (select emp_id, name, role from employee 
        where 
        1 = 1 
        AND
        emp_id =? 
        AND
        name = ?
        AND
        role = ?
        order by emp_id asc)  origQry

) fullData where rownum <= ?
) where rnum > ?;
```

I can do this with hibernate native sql parameterized query language.
For Example:-

```
    SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery("select * from (select ROWNUM rnum,fullData.* from (select count(*) over () as rowcnt,origQry.* from (select emp_id, name, role from employee where 1 = 1 AND    emp_id =? AND name = ? AND role = ? order by emp_id asc)  origQry) fullData where rownum <= ?) where rnum > ?");
sqlQuery.setParameter(1,someValye);
sqlQuery.setParameter(2,someValye);
sqlQuery.setParameter(3,someValye);
sqlQuery.setParameter(4,someValye);
sqlQuery.setParameter(5,someValye);
```

But the problem is, it is not always required to add all three attributes (emp_id, name, role) in origQry where claue.
Whenever the values comes for these attribute from the user input then only it should get added in origQry where calues.

If it is possible to use any other method than native query language, i would be okay to use that.
Please suggest some solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually use JPA (and not Hibernate proprietary annotations), you may create a [dynamic query](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/Dynamic-Queries) and build `WHERE` criteria like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57462583).